# Unsetting index in array turns it to an object

Tags: php, arrays, json, unset

So I have a JSON document I'm storing in CouchDB.  Here's the important part of it:

```
"games": {
   "creator": [
       "cf86d68b24c1bbf22702356572027642",
       "cf86d68b24c1bbf22702356572027dd8",
       "cf86d68b24c1bbf22702356572028b77"
   ],
   "solver": {
   }
}
```

I'm trying to remove one item from the array, let's say index 1:

```
error_log("pre unset: " . json_encode($user->games));
unset($user->games->creator[1]);
error_log("post unset: " . json_encode($user->games));
```

The problem is, it keeps converting my array to an object, like so:

```
pre unset: {"creator":["cf86d68b24c1bbf22702356572027642","cf86d68b24c1bbf22702356572027dd8","cf86d68b24c1bbf22702356572028b77"],"solver":{}}
post unset: {"creator":{"0":"cf86d68b24c1bbf22702356572027642","2":"cf86d68b24c1bbf22702356572028b77"},"solver":{}}
```

What's going on, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
unset($user->games->creator[1]);
$user->games->creator = array_values($user->games->creator);
```

Comment: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `unset`, use `array_splice`. This will automatically adjust the array indexes:

```
array_splice($user->games->creator, 1, 1);
```