# PHP - JSON saved in a wrong format when unset a value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array of videos Ids and when a user clicks on a button the videoId of the clicked video appends to the array.

When the user clicks again on the same button, the code search for the videoId and if it is found, the video ID is deleted from the array.

The array is saved on a json file and its formatted as `["aaa","bob"...]` however, when I delete a value from the array the json file is transformed to `{"1":"aaa", "2":"bbb"...}`

How can I prevent this from Happening?

PHP:

```
$NameFileJSON = $_GET["NameFile"];
$VideoId = $_GET["VideoId"];
$removeVideoId = $_GET["RemoveVideoId"];

$results = array($VideoId);
```

SAVE VIDEOID:

```
if (($NameFileJSON != "")&&($VideoId != "")&&($removeVideoId == "")){

        $filename = "json/likesJSON/$NameFileJSON.json";

        if (file_exists($filename)) {

            echo "The file $filename exist";

            $inp = file_get_contents("json/likesJSON/$NameFileJSON.json");
            $arr = json_decode($inp);

            array_push($arr, $results[0]);

            $fp_login = fopen("json/$NameFileJSON.json", w);
            fwrite($fp_login, json_encode($arr));
            fclose($fp_login);

        } else {

             echo "The file $filename does not exist";
            $fp_login = fopen("json/$NameFileJSON.json", w);
            fwrite($fp_login, json_encode($results));
            fclose($fp_login);

        }
```

}

DELETE VIDEOID:

```
if (($NameFileJSON != "")&&($VideoId == "")&&($removeVideoId != "")){

    $inp = file_get_contents("json/$NameFileJSON.json");
            $arr = json_decode($inp);

    if (($index = array_search($removeVideoId, $arr)) !== false) {
        echo  $index;
        unset($arr[$index]);
    }

            $fp_login = fopen("json/$NameFileJSON.json", w);
            fwrite($fp_login, json_encode($arr));
            fclose($fp_login);      

}

print_r(json_encode($arr)
```

Comment: Did you try `Array.splice()` in JavaScript instead of `delete`? Or, what do you mean by delete?

Comment: it's php-side behavior. `array_values` can help here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same @Barry said, if you still want save as array in json, you can use this

```
if (($NameFileJSON != "")&&($VideoId == "")&&($removeVideoId != "")){

    $inp = file_get_contents("json/$NameFileJSON.json");
            $arr = json_decode($inp);

    if (($index = array_search($removeVideoId, $arr)) !== false) {
        echo  $index;
        unset($arr[$index]);
    }
    $arr = array_values($arr);

            $fp_login = fopen("json/$NameFileJSON.json", w);
            fwrite($fp_login, json_encode($arr));
            fclose($fp_login);      

}

print_r(json_encode($arr)
```

see more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 0):

[json_encode turns array into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878219/json-encode-turns-array-into-an-object)
use json_encode flags to force it to an array

[Unsetting index in array turns it to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346676/unsetting-index-in-array-turns-it-to-an-object)
ensure it's not an assoc array after using unset

Comment: The answer in the first link says how to use flags in `json_decode`, not `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` will only produce array notation if the array indexes are sequental numbers starting from `0`. When you use `unset()`, it creates a gap in the indexes, so it's sent as an object to maintain the indexes. For this reason, `unset()` should generally only be used with associative arrays.

Use `array_splice()` rather than `unset()` to remove an element from the array, and then all the indexes after it will be shifted down.

```
array_splice($arr, $index, 1);
```

Comment: Related answer from same contributor posted 7 minutes later: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577696/2943403

Answer (score 0):

1. You can replace your `unset` with `array_splice`:
   `array_splice($array, $i, 1);`
2. You can reset indexes with `array_values`:
   `json_encode(array_values($array));`